# Como criar arquivo.php utilizando php?

Tags: php, html

A ideia é montar um sistema de notícias, assim que eu preencher a página de notícias e clicar em publicar, deve gerar um arquivo .php com o conteúdo da notícia.

Fazer esse conteúdo eu devo conseguir, eu só queria saber como eu faço para gerar esse arquivo.php utilizando o proprio PHP.

Comment: Não deveria usar o banco de dados para armazenar as informações? se quiser criar o arquivo é só usar o `file_put_content()` ou `fopen()/fwrite()`

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/427668-criar-arquivophp-com-php/

Comment: eu não sei, sou novato, a ideia era criar o arquivo e deixar o arquivo com o conteúdo dentro no banco, como seu eu tivesse criado manualmente, como se fosse estático

Comment: A melhor solução é armazená-la em banco de dados mesmo. Se não souber, essa é a melhor hora para aprender. O que você pode fazer depois é gerar páginas HTML estáticas para servir de cachê, mas começa primeiro servindo o conteúdo dinâmico a partir do banco.

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus, Cara até existem possibilidades de você fazer isso, mas não é viável não, seu site vai ficar muito vulnerável, nunca permita o próprio usuário escrever um arquivo php, php é uma linguagem a nível de servidor. Crie um banco de dados onde você armazene esses textos e exiba os conteúdos usando templates.

Comment: eu pensei em criar um banco e armazenar os textos lá, porém não sei como dar continuidade no processo, alguém tem algum tópico que eu possa estudar sobre o assunto?

Answer (score 9):

Basicamente:

```
<?php

     $conteudo = '<?php phpinfo(); ?>';

     file_put_contents('novophp.php', $conteudo);
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php

Ou assim:

```
$conteudo = '<?php phpinfo(); ?>';

$arquivo = fopen('novophp.php', 'w');
fwrite($arquivo, $conteudo);
fclose($arquivo);
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php

### Tendo respondido, algumas considerações

Provavelmente não é isso que você quer. Antes de mais nada, para fazer o que foi proposto, precisa ter permissões de escrita nos diretórios onde for gerar os PHP. Além disso, a manutenção seria extremamente sofrida quando o conteúdo fosse alterado. Provavelmente, como já comentado, você deveria pensar em uma opção com base de dados.

Existem casos legítimos onde gerar um `.html` estático pode ser interessante, e economizar muitos recursos do servidor, apenas alterando e/ou removendo esses arquivos quando alterar algo no DB. Eu acho uma estratégia muito boa para sistemas de CMS, mas deixe isto para quando dominar o essencial.

Comment: Sim, estou pensando na versão utilizando banco de dados, estou estudando para conseguir fazer isso, sem utilizar framework eu consigo fazer isso?

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus não uso frameworks em PHP. Tem quem goste, não é meu caso. O que o PHP tem de nativo é mais eficiente e vai direto ao ponto para praticamente qualquer coisa. Quando você chegar na parte de rotas (decidir o que fazer conforme o URL que o usuário digitou), se fizer um _benchmark_, vai ver que  os frameworks em geral costumam ser uma "carroça" comparado a soluções diretas, como arquivos separados e boa organização. FW de PHP usualmente serve para "pensar menos" e "enrolar cliente". Nenhuma das 2 coisas me interessa :)